# Create Ethereum Adress

Tags: myetherwallet, addresses

Is it possible to create an Ethereum Adress in MEW (MyEtherWallet) entirely offline and then send tokens to it or do I have to at least activate it one time online?

Comment: No you can create an Ethereum wallet address everywhere. With the following script you can create wallet addresses from your command line tool https://github.com/Robbertvermeulen/generate-ethereum-wallet-credentials

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create an Ethereum Adress in MEW (MyEtherWallet) entirely offline

Yes, you can download the tool [directly from GitHub](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/tag/v3.10.9.7). If you're worried about following links that people post in online forums - and you should be(!) - see the instructions on the MEW website:

https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/offline/running-myetherwallet-locally.html

If you'd prefer to find the above link yourself, it can be found in the bottom right of the MEW homepage.

> do I have to at least activate it one time online?

No, that's not necessary.

Clearly there are other tools for generating wallets offline, but you need a way to be able to maximise your trust in them. If you are able to read and understand the source code of those tools, then fine. If you can't, then using something like MEW, which has built a strong reputation over time, is a good (the best?) alternative.

Comment: What is used as an entropy when generating the wallet?